# If $A_n$ is some specific $3 \times 3$ matrix, then ${A_n}^n = I$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, euclidean-geometry, matrix-equations

**Introduction :**

Suppose $n$ is a natural number which is equal to or greater than $5$.

Let's think of regular $n$-gon in any Euclidean space, and denote $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ the points of regular $n$-gon on the counterclockwise way.

Define $c_n$ by $\frac{sin\frac{3\pi}{n}}{sin\frac{\pi}{n}}$, it is the ratio of second small diagonal (of regular $n$-gon) to one side (of that regular $n$-gon).

Then we can easily get the following equations:

$x_4 - x_1 = c_n (x_3 - x_2)$

$x_5 - x_2 = c_n (x_4 - x_3)$

$\vdots$

$x_3 - x_n = c_n (x_2 - x_1)$

Generally, let's define $a_{i+3}=c_n a_{i+2}-c_n a_{i+1} +a_i$ 
for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

If we assign $a_1 = x_1, a_2 = x_2, a_3 = x_3$, then we get 
$a_m = x_m$ for all $m \in \lbrace 1,2,\ldots, n \rbrace$, and 
$a_{n+1}=a_1, a_{n+2}=a_2, a_{n+3}=a_3$.

**Question :**

If $a_{i+3}=c_n a_{i+2}-c_n a_{i+1} +a_i$ 
for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$ with any initial values of $a_1, a_2, a_3$, then I guess that the equations $a_{n+1}=a_1, a_{n+2}=a_2, a_{n+3}=a_3$ are also true.

It is equivalent to the following question :

Let $A_n = \pmatrix {0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -c_n & c_n}$, 
then is $\left(A_n\right)^n$ equal to $I$?

I've checked that it is true where $n=5,6,7$.

It is easy to check when $n=6$. In this case, $c_6 = 2$,

$A_6 = \pmatrix {0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & 2}$,

and 
$\left(A_6\right)^6 = \pmatrix {0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & 2}^6 = I$.

**Motivation :**

If this conjecture is true, then the following interesting result is also true.

In any Euclidean space, choose any three points $P_1, P_2, P_3$, and 
choose any $c_n$ which is defined in Introduction. 
Then for $i=4,5,6,\ldots$, define $P_i$ recursively by $P_i - P_{i-3} = c_n (P_{i-1}-P_{i-2})$.

It means that $\overline{P_i P_{i-3}}$ is parallel to 
$\overline{P_{i-1} P_{i-2}}$, and the ratio of $\overline{P_i P_{i-3}}$ to 
$\overline{P_{i-1} P_{i-2}}$ is $c_n$ for any $i = 4,5,6, \ldots$.

Then surprisingly $P_{n+1}$ is $P_1$, $P_{n+2}$ is $P_2$, and $P_{n+3}$ is $P_3$.

Comment: Yes, $A_n^n=I$. The off-diagonal coefficients of $A_n^n$ are polynomials in $c_n$, which are zero for the above choice of $c_n$. I suppose there is a nice way to show this (I did not try).

Comment: Thanks for comment. How could you convince that the off-diagonal coefficients are zero?

Comment: Just by computer. I suppose we obtain certain well-known polynomials. Did you try to write down the polynomials occuring in $A_n^5,A_n^6,A_n^7,\cdots ,A_n^n$?

Comment: Which software did you use? I don't know how to solve this problem by computer.

Comment: Then how could you check $n=5,6,7$? You can use any CAS, like Maple, Mathematica etc. to compute these polynomials.

Comment: I understand your intend. Thank you! I will try again soon.

Comment: When $n=5,6,7$, I checked by my hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $c_n=2\cos(2\pi/n)+1$ and that $A_n$ is the companion matrix of the  polynomial $x^3-c_nx^2+c_nx-1=(x-1)(x^2-(c_n-1)x+1)=(x-1)(x^2-2\cos(2\pi/n)x+1)$.

To show that $A_n^n=I_3$, it suffices to show that the roots of $x^2-2\cos(2\pi/n)x+1$ are not $1$, are distinct and satisfy $x^n=1$. That is the case because the considered roots are $e^{\pm 2i\pi/n}$.